# ALSA driver for USB modem external audio codec on SoC

Tags: linux, driver, embedded-linux, modem, alsa

I have an USB modem which exports a PCM interface, fed to an I2C audio codec.

[image: connection schematic]

The codec is supported as a SoC ALSA codec, and I'm developing a driver to manage the sound levels through ALSA mixers.

I think I have two options:

- either create a dummy SoC sound card with the codec as an aux (`snd_soc_aux_dev`) device. The codec's configuration is fixed in the init() function and ALSA is not managing the PCM interface, just the levels. This way I'm not using all the functions already implemented in the codec's driver to set clocks, rates, formats.
- or create a modem sound card which exports a DAI with the correct rate and format parameters. This way I can use the codec driver's implementation of all the functions.

Which place should I put this kind of driver? As an extension to the USB driver, or as a SoC one?

Comment: How will you be exporting the DAI from the modem sound card? You can try and place such kind of driver in the SoC layer that is acting as a master.